# How to add colors to integer values inside a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, integer, colorama

I want to add green color to an integer value which is <= 5 and red color to an integer value >5 , inside a dictionary in python.

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
input_dict = {'key1': 217, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 9, 'key4': 4, 'key5':6}
for key in input_dict:
    if input_dict[key] < 5:
        <# print input_dict with integer values in red color #>
    if output[key]>5:
        <# print input_dict with integer values in red color #>

expected output = {'key1': 217 (217 value printed in red color), 'key2': 2 (2 value printed in green color), 'key3': 9 (9 value printed in red color), 'key4': 4 (4 value printed in green color), 'key5': 6 (6 value printed in red color)}
```

expected output_dictionary = {'key1': 217 (value printed in red color), 'key2': 2 (value printed in green color), 'key3': 9 (value printed in red), 'key4': 4 (value printed in green color), 'key5': 6 (value printed in red color)}

I request your help sincere help here.

Comment: Integers don't have colors... What are you expecting the dict to look like?

Comment: It sounds like you want to either associate some color value with your integers, in a separate field of some aggregate type, or convert them to a string format that supports color codes (e.g. ansi color), in which case they are no longer integers.  You need to decide what you want your representation to look like, giving a concrete example of it.  The example given is nonsensical, since standard integers don't have color properties.

Comment: I have re-edited the question for better understanding

Comment: It doesn't help.  Give a concrete example of what you want.  Saying something like "217 (value printed in red color)" is meaningless.  It's not valid Python syntax.  What value do you want in place of 217?  Show it.  You have not asked a meaningful question.  You have been told why it's not meaningful.  How do you want to encode the color information?  Do you want to use a tuple, e.g. `(217, "red")`?  Or do you want to encode is as ansi string escapes?  *Be concrete.*  If you can't say what you want, then no one can help you.

Comment: Even if you do store ANSI colored strings in your dictionary, you probably won't see the colors if you print the whole thing, since printing a dictionary prints the `repr` of its contents. The `repr` of a string will escape non-printable characters, like the Escape character that leads off each ANSI sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [colorama PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) is pretty clear on how to access the ANSI escape sequences that need to be printed to change the color of **printed** text. However, it is quite important to note that:

> *Even if you do store ANSI colored strings in your dictionary, you probably won't see the colors if you print the whole thing, since printing a dictionary prints the repr of its contents. The repr of a string will escape non-printable characters, like the Escape character that leads off each ANSI sequence.* - [Blckknght](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1405065/blckknght)

So, even if you stored the values like

```py
# !pip install colorama
# from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
input_dict = {'key1': 217, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 9, 'key4': 4, 'key5':6}

colored_dict = {k: f'{Fore.RED if v>5 else Fore.GREEN}{v}' for k, v in input_dict.items()}
```

`colored_dict` would just look like

> ```py
> {'key1': '\x1b[31m217',
>  'key2': '\x1b[32m2',
>  'key3': '\x1b[31m9',
>  'key4': '\x1b[32m4',
>  'key5': '\x1b[31m6'}
> ```

Although, if you printed those saved values separately<sup>([view examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duOsx.png))</sup>, the colors will show (just **remember to reset so that the color** doesn't run on to the next print).

---

If you just wanted to fill in your code snippet, then: <sup>([view output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTfuM.png))</sup>

```py
for key in input_dict:
    if input_dict[key] > 5:
        print(repr(key)+':', Fore.RED, input_dict[key], Fore.RESET)
        # print input_dict with integer values in red color #
    else:
        print(repr(key)+':', Fore.GREEN, input_dict[key], Fore.RESET)
        # print input_dict with integer values in green color #
```

---

If you want it to be printed looking like a dictionary, then:

```py
## setup
thresh, cHi, cLo = 5, Fore.RED, Fore.GREEN
cKey, cNorm = Fore.BLUE, Fore.RESET ## set Fore.RESET for cKey as well to NOT color keys
input_dict = {'key1': 217, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 9, 'key4': 4, 'key5': 6}
def colorFunc(kx, vx): 
    return cKey+repr(kx)+': '+(cHi if vx>thresh else cLo)+repr(vx)+cNorm
```

```py
# one line:
print('{', ', '.join(colorFunc(k,v) for k,v in input_dict.items()), '}', sep='')
```

```py
# multi-line:
print('{\n ', ',\n '.join(colorFunc(k,v) for k,v in input_dict.items()), '\n}', sep='')
```

> [image: op]